# Using ajax in liferay

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, liferay

I have a portlet with a button in it. when this button clicked I send an ajax request to one of my controller in my project and get back result in normal case I did it like this:

***web.xml***:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ctrl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controller.Translator_ctrl</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ctrl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/translate</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

***view.jsp***:

```
function send_form(){
            var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
            var base;
            var from=document.getElementById("from").value;
            var to=document.getElementById("to").value;
            var lang_from=document.getElementById("lang_from").value;
            var lang_to=document.getElementById("lang_to").value;
            //alert(":D:D:D"+from+"::::"+to+":::"+lang_from+":::"+lang_to);
            xhr.onreadystatechange=function (){
                if(xhr.readyState==4){
                    base=xhr.responseText;
                    //document.getElementById("to").value=base;
                    alert(base);
                }
            }
            xhr.open("GET","translate?mode=ajax&from="+from+"&to="+to+"&lang_from="+lang_from+"&lang_to="+lang_to,true);
            xhr.send();
        }
```

Now I do not know how to do it in Liferay? How can I do this in Liferay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

utilize the "resource" lifecycle, which is there for exactly this purpose. You'll send the request to  and implement the `serveResource` method in your portlet (using whatever implementation/framework you use). The code that goes it there is basically the same as you had in the servlet when you didn't use a portal environment

Comment: When I used servlets I used to map the servlet to a special URL and send the ajax request directly to that URL.
Now where should I send ajax request to?

Comment: to <portlet:resourceURL/> - the first thing you loose control over in a portal environment is the URL, thus, the portal will generate it for you. You can gain some control back later (when you want to have 'pretty' URLs), but start with the technical necessities and continue to work from there.